# Absolute Z-Index over Fixed Z-Index

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking at doing my own tooltips and as it stands they work very well. They are a `position: absolute` tooltip.

The only issue I seem to have with them at the moment is that I have a `position: fixed` navbar and when I add a tooltip to this navbar (the tooltip having a `z-index: 999` and the navbar having a `z-index: 100`), the tooltip does not show.

I know for a fact it is the `position: fixed` of the navbar that is causing this but I'm not sure of a way round. When I remove `position: fixed` it seems to work correctly.

Below is an attached image of what the issue is.

[image: Issue with z-index and position]

Comment: In order to help you effectively we'd need to see your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, absolute position z-index always are in relation to their relative parent element and to each other, BUT only to the siblings inside the same parent.

When you have a fixed position element, you need another fixed position element with a higher z-index to appear above it.